# Getting huge response from an API with HttpClient and storing it in JArray

Tags: c#, json.net, httpclient

I have a scenario where I need to get data of 10000 people from an API. Unfortunately, the API provider doesn't have paging in place (sad ). Now I have to be very careful while handling this case. All I want to do is download this data and save it in JArray for further process I want to do on each object.

I tried following every other best practice to fetch huge data using HttpClient and store it in JArray but I got `System.OutOfMemoryException` on Newtonsoft.Json.

Here's how my code block looks like -

```
public async Task<JArray> GetContactsObject(ConnectorToken token)
{
        JArray contacts = new JArray();

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

                string requestUrl = "<api_uri>";


                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", GenearateHeaders("GET", requestUrl, token));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");

                using (Stream s = await client.GetStreamAsync(requestUrl))
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    contacts = JArray.Load(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Fatal(ex);
        }
        return contacts;
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? The API response is huge, it has 10,000 contacts and approx size of response is around 70-80mb.

**Updated snippet - still throws exception but an improvement I would say**

```
public async Task<MailPlusContacts> GetContactsObject(ConnectorToken token)
        {
            MailPlusContacts contacts = new MailPlusContacts();

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

                    string requestUrl = "<api_uri>";


                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", GenearateHeaders("GET", requestUrl, token));

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");



                    using (Stream s = await client.GetStreamAsync(requestUrl))
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                    using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                    {

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                            {
                                // Load each object from the stream and do something with it
                                JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
                                contacts.Contacts.Add(obj);
                            }


                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }

            return contacts;
        }
```

Sample JSON (1 object, consider 10k of these)

```
[
    {
        "externalId": "4D8C802F4DE244248D97E8C80F628AF3",
        "created": 1471413089000,
        "encryptedId": "bbhjZi4UYIiYnnZ",
        "testGroup": false,
        "lastChanged": 1476683221000,
        "temporary": false,
        "properties": {
            "prop1": "11:09",
            "birthdate": "1991-07-01",
            "freeField1": "*1000000000*",
            "freeField2": "Y",
            "street": "Shivaji Nagar",
            "houseNumber": "123",
            "city": "Pune",
            "list4": [
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item",
                    "bit": 1,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 2",
                    "bit": 2,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 3",
                    "bit": 4,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 23-1-2016",
                    "bit": 8,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 2 23-1-2016",
                    "bit": 16,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 2 27-1-2016",
                    "bit": 32,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Meeloopdagen",
                    "bit": 64,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 2 5-3-2016",
                    "bit": 128,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 5-3-2016",
                    "bit": 256,
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 2 Chemie 1-3-2016",
                    "bit": 512,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 2 Chemie 8-3-2016",
                    "bit": 1024,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 23-4-2016",
                    "bit": 2048,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "dropdown item 2 23-4-2016",
                    "bit": 4096,
                    "enabled": false
                }
            ],
            "list5": [
                {
                    "description": "Ja",
                    "bit": 1,
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Nee",
                    "bit": 2,
                    "enabled": false
                }
            ],
            "list2": [
                {
                    "description": "Test Werk en Test",
                    "bit": 1,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Test Test",
                    "bit": 2,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Psychologie",
                    "bit": 4,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Therapie",
                    "bit": 8,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 16,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 32,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Bio-Test",
                    "bit": 64,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 128,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Economie",
                    "bit": 256,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 512,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "HBO-Test",
                    "bit": 1024,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Sociaal Test Test",
                    "bit": 2048,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Human Test Test",
                    "bit": 4096,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test en Test",
                    "bit": 8192,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 16384,
                    "enabled": false
                }
            ],
            "postalCode": "1201AX",
            "list3": [
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 1,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 2,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "DTest 1",
                    "bit": 4,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 8,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "LTest 1",
                    "bit": 16,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 32,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "PTest 1",
                    "bit": 64,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 128,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "STest 1",
                    "bit": 256,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "TTest 1",
                    "bit": 512,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "MTest 1",
                    "bit": 1024,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "KTest 1",
                    "bit": 2048,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 4096,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1e",
                    "bit": 8192,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 16384,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1n",
                    "bit": 32768,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "PTest 1jk",
                    "bit": 65536,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "BTest 1a",
                    "bit": 131072,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "BTest 1ek ",
                    "bit": 262144,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 524288,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 1048576,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1 Economie",
                    "bit": 2097152,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test ",
                    "bit": 4194304,
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "HBO-Test",
                    "bit": 8388608,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Test Test",
                    "bit": 16777216,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test in de Test",
                    "bit": 33554432,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Resource Test",
                    "bit": 67108864,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Test",
                    "bit": 134217728,
                    "enabled": false
                }
            ],
            "phoneNumber": "0793631212",
            "initials": "Rahul",
            "list1": [
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 1,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 2",
                    "bit": 2,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 3",
                    "bit": 4,
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 4",
                    "bit": 8,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 5",
                    "bit": 16,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 6",
                    "bit": 32,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "tet7 ",
                    "bit": 64,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 8",
                    "bit": 128,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 256,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 512,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 1024,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 2048,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 4096,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 8192,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 16384,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 32768,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 65536,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 131072,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 262144,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 524288,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 1048576,
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1 Economie",
                    "bit": 2097152,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 4194304,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "HBO-Test 1",
                    "bit": 8388608,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1 ",
                    "bit": 16777216,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 33554432,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 67108864,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test 1",
                    "bit": 134217728,
                    "enabled": false
                }
            ],
            "gender": "M",
            "firstName": "Rahul Patil",
            "list6": [
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 1,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test ",
                    "bit": 2,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test ",
                    "bit": 4,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test ",
                    "bit": 8,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Test",
                    "bit": 16,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 32,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Test Test",
                    "bit": 64,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test-Test Test",
                    "bit": 128,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test in de Test",
                    "bit": 256,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Test Test Test",
                    "bit": 512,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Test",
                    "bit": 1024,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Test en Test",
                    "bit": 2048,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Therapie",
                    "bit": 4096,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 8192,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Resource Test",
                    "bit": 16384,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "HBO-Test",
                    "bit": 32768,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 65536,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test Test",
                    "bit": 131072,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 262144,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test",
                    "bit": 524288,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Bio-Test",
                    "bit": 1048576,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Test en Test Test",
                    "bit": 2097152,
                    "enabled": false
                }
            ],
            "date1": "2016-09-30",
            "lastName": "Patil",
            "organisation": "Test Organization",
            "email": "john@doe.com",
            "vrij15": "N",
            "profileFields": [
                {
                    "description": "testField",
                    "bit": 1,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "test1",
                    "bit": 2,
                    "enabled": true
                }
            ],
            "profileField2": "asd",
            "numeric1": "10",
            "profileField1": "asd",
            "profileField3": "asd"
        },
        "channels": [
            {
                "name": "EMAIL",
                "value": true
            },
            {
                "name": "SMS",
                "value": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Anyway, you should process each json token with `reader` and store only the necessary values in a List or Dictionary instead of parsing the whole array.  Take a look [Read JSON with JsonTextReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/readjsonwithjsontextreader.htm)

Comment: @wdosanjos you should write a real answer.

Comment: I think this `contacts = JArray.Load(reader);` is the culprit. Your memory is going well over 80mb. You might want to consider [Flat buffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)

Comment: @wdosanjos I tried doing the way they have said to implement with JsonTextReader. Still throws me System.OutOfMemory Exception. Code snippet updated above.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your json?

Comment: @wdosanjos posted a sample json of single object. consider such 10k objects

Comment: @PeterChaula Flat buffers in c# do not support JSON parsing yet. Any code sample that can help me though?

Comment: Do you need to keep all those properties available for each contact?  If not, what properties do you need available to process later?

Comment: I will need all the properties unfortunately. And the JSON that comes from API can be dynamic. The properties are not fixed :-)

Comment: yes they do not support @RahulPatil. It's not JSON but you get good memory efficiency

Comment: @PeterChaula still looking for better alternative to `JsonTextReader`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will need to break up the object manually.
The parsing that is occurring in the creation of 'JObject.Load(reader);' is massive in this case.

Or their could be problems with the JObject growing a certain amount, dynamically resizing for really big objects can cause problems.

I'd bet you'll have more luck pulling it in as a string.

```
 //Read raw json as a string from the body of the HTTP post, and don’t parse it
 string results = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Its possible that parsing that massive string would parse better if it is a string first.

But you might find its still too big, at which time you'll want to do part of the parsing yourself. Doing it the "fun" way as I call it:

find a starting object of the array then count the brackets
example: if your data returned

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

You'd want to do this:

```
var headerIndex = '{"employees":['.Length;
var startIndex = result.IndexOf('{',headerIndex);
if(startIndex != -1)
{
    var bracketcount = 1;
    int rowCount;
    for(rowCount = 0; i < int.MaxValue && bracketcount != 0)
    {
        if (result[i] == '{') bracketcount++;
        if(result[i] == '}') bracketcount--;
    }

    var smallerObjectString = result.SubString(0,rowCount);
    //create a single object and handle it
```

Comment: I will give it a try ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The response may "only" be 80MB (that is an enormous text response), but to represent that as a hierarchy of objects in memory can take up significantly more space.

JSON.NET is able to deserialize from a stream so the entire string isn't being loaded into memory. Instead, the most likely culprit is the fact that you're storing everything in a single `contacts` variable and a `JArray` most likely parses every child node within it.

Here are some [JSON.NET performance tips](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) to guard against running out of memory.